ADS Schematic vs Layout Error
I’m trying to create a 3dB power divider in order to create a 1x2 patch antenna in ADS. Currently I have the following schematic below:
For the MLIN (TL6 and TL7) these components come up highlight and mention that they’re not in the schematic, I’ve kept the values as the 70.7 ohms linecalc. How can I fix this? With out these components it works fine and s parameters are good, but they’re just too close together and the patch antenna would overlap if I don’t add extra MLIN before the Bends.


@Neil_UK My apologies. I have updates the OP with a screenshot instead

It says they're not in the layout, not 'not in the schematic'. Do the other MLIN's appear in the layout? It mentions a synchronise step, have you done this?

@Neil_UK Yes the other MLIN's do appear in the layout and they don't show up as a problem. I'm trying right now to find out how I can synchronize as I haven't done it before.

can't seem to solve this

Can you share your layout as well? The message hints at the error being there, not in the schematic. Also, check the "Design Differences" window, available from both schematic (Layout -> Design Differences) and layout (Schematic -> Design Differences). You should be able to place the missing components from there.
